# Outlook Add-In in Angular 5: Can't resolve all parameters for component

Tags: dependency-injection, angular5, outlook-addin

I'm using Angular 5 to create an Outlook add-in. I used Yeoman to generate the files, not angular-cli. I have a service that I wrote, MeetingsService, that I'm trying to inject into one of my components, BehaviorsSearchComponent. I listed my service as a provider in AppModule, and I imported it in BehaviorsSearchComponent. When I run my add-in, I get the error

```
Can't resolve all parameters for BehaviorsSearchComponent: (?)
```

It works if I do

```
constructor (@Inject(MeetingsService) meetingsService: MeetingsService)
```

But I'd like to be able to do it without the @Inject. I also tried importing core-js/es7/reflect in my taskpane.ts file, which is my root file. I checked my webpack.config and babel/polyfill is specified for my entry polyfill. I don't think it's a circular dependency issue; I installed that package and I didn't get any warnings in the build.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some issue with a dependency in my package.lock.json? My @angular packages are either 5.2.11 or 5.2.5.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
import { MeetingsService } from './meetings.service';
import AppComponent from './app.component';
import { BehaviorsSearchComponent } from './behaviors-search/behaviors-search.component';
import { EnableAddInComponent } from './enable-addIn/enable-addIn.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    MeetingsService
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BehaviorsSearchComponent,
    EnableAddInComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export default class AppModule { }
```

**meetings.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MeetingsService {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**behaviors-search.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MeetingsService } from '../meetings.service';
...

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'src/taskpane/app/behaviors-search/behaviors-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['src/taskpane/app/shared.css']
})

export class BehaviorsSearchComponent {

  constructor(private meetingsService: MeetingsService) {}

  ...
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const fs = require("fs");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const config = {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      polyfill: "@babel/polyfill",
      taskpane: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "ts-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
          use: "file-loader"
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "taskpane.html",
        template: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane"]
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          to: "taskpane.css",
          from: "./src/taskpane/taskpane.css"
        }
      ]),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"]
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },      
      https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000
    }
  };

  return config;
};
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Injecting as `constructor (@Inject(MeetingsService) meetingsService: MeetingsService)` seems to be the only way, because the project generated with Yeoman (`yo office`) uses webpack instead of Angular CLI

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Angular/issues/45#issuecomment-586167019